# how to add method with gsub to text_field ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new to rails and ruby, sorry if it's too noobish to ask but need help cause i'm stuck.

i have simple 'app', using rails forms. I need to change ( . ) into ( : ) whenever user will fill the text_field on form.

can anyone be so kind and help me create method from scratch, to access   text_field : appearance    and use gsub method on it to change ( . ) into ( : ) ?

here is my view: (model is empty, controller is generated using scaffold, super simple stuff)

```
    <%= form_for(@sample) do |f| %>
  <% if @sample.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@sample.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this sample from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @sample.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :appearance %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :appearance %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model, try this:

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  def appearance=(value)
    write_attribute(:appearance, value.gsub(/\./, ':'))
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it solve my confusion. tbh it is harder than i thought.

Comment: done :) i'm new to this page, so i didn't even know about having to accept the answer :) thanks again!